# When analytical and numerical methods do not agree - Case study with Maximum Likelihoods methods

Tags: numerical-integration, probability-or-statistics, distributions

Here is the probability distribution I am interested in:

$$P(q)=C e^{4 n s q} q^{4 n \nu - 1} (1 - q)^{4 n \mu - 1}$$

, where $e$ is the constant of Euler and $C$ is constant so that the whole thing integrates to 1. $n$, $\mu$, $\nu$ and $s$ are four parameters of the distribution. **My goal is to use a maximum likelihood method in order to estimate the most likely value of the parameter $s$ given the other parameters and given the variable $q$. But I am encountering some issues related with different results obtained when using analytical versus numerical methods. Can you help me to solve this issue?**

---

**Below is what I tried...**

I first tried to find the value for $C$ so I did:

```
1/(Gamma[4 n \[Mu]] Gamma[4 n \[Nu]] Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[
     4 n \[Nu], 4 n (\[Mu] + \[Nu]), 4 n s]) E^(4 n s q) q^(
   4 n \[Nu] - 1) (1 - q)^(4 n \[Mu] - 1) /. s -> \[Mu]/10 /. 
 q -> 0.75
```

and got

```
1/(Gamma[4 n \[Mu]] Gamma[4 n \[Nu]] Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[
         4 n \[Nu], 4 n (\[Mu] + \[Nu]), 4 n s]) E^(4 n s q) q^(
       4 n \[Nu] - 1) (1 - q)^(4 n \[Mu] - 1) /. s -> \[Mu]/10 /. 
     q -> 0.75
```

Given that conditions are always respected for the range of parameters I want to consider, I am satisfy with this answer. As a quick check, I made sure that it indeed integrates to one for a realistc choice of parameters by running.

```
\[Mu] = 10^-6
\[Nu] = \[Mu]
n = 100/(40 \[Nu])
Integrate[
 Re[1/(Gamma[4 n \[Mu]] Gamma[4 n \[Nu]] Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[
      4 n \[Nu], 4 n (\[Mu] + \[Nu]), 4 n s]) E^(4 n s q) q^(
    4 n \[Nu] - 1) (1 - q)^(4 n \[Mu] - 1) /. s -> \[Mu]/10], {q, 0, 
  1}]
```

And indeed it integrates to 1. However, if I use `NIntegrate`...

```
NIntegrate[
     Re[1/(Gamma[4 n \[Mu]] Gamma[4 n \[Nu]] Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[
          4 n \[Nu], 4 n (\[Mu] + \[Nu]), 4 n s]) E^(4 n s q) q^(
        4 n \[Nu] - 1) (1 - q)^(4 n \[Mu] - 1) /. s -> \[Mu]/10], {q, 0, 
      1}]
```

it does not at all integrate to one (it integrates to 0.0000538285). If I calculate for the probability for a given $q$

```
1/(Gamma[4 n \[Mu]] Gamma[4 n \[Nu]] Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[
     4 n \[Nu], 4 n (\[Mu] + \[Nu]), 4 n s]) E^(4 n s q) q^(
   4 n \[Nu] - 1) (1 - q)^(4 n \[Mu] - 1) /. s -> \[Mu]/10 /. 
 q -> 0.75
```

I get some tiny probability (0.0000181795 in this case). This probability corresponds to what can be seen when we graph the probability distribution:

```
Plot[1/(Gamma[4 n \[Mu]] Gamma[
     4 n \[Nu]] Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[4 n \[Nu], 
     4 n (\[Mu] + \[Nu]), 4 n s]) E^(4 n s q ) q^(
   4 n \[Nu] - 1) (1 - q)^(4 n \[Mu] - 1) /. s -> \[Mu]/10, {q, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Looking at this graph, it is obvious that it actually does not integrate to 1.

Below is my attempt to visualize the log-likelihood curve (for each $s$ considered)

```
searchS = Table[s, {s, 0, 1, 0.001}];
likelihoods = List[];
Do[s = searchS[[i]];
 likelihoods = 
  Append[likelihoods, 
   1/(Gamma[4 n \[Mu]] Gamma[4 n \[Nu]] Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[
      4 n \[Nu], 4 n (\[Mu] + \[Nu]), 4 n s]) E^(4 n s q ) q^(
    4 n \[Nu] - 1) (1 - q)^(4 n \[Mu] - 1)]
 , {i, 1, Length[searchS]}]
loglikelihoods = Log[likelihoods];
ListPlot[Transpose[{searchS, loglikelihoods}], 
 AxesLabel -> {"s", "log(likelihood)"}]
```

[image]

which is definitely not what I expected.

Comment: I suspect `Integrate` is coming up with a bad antiderivative. Will investigate.

Comment: @Daniel: I don't think so. Integrate behaves well (Version 8) (see my answer).

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze Thanks for the observation and response, that might save me some trouble. (That, or double it, if both `Integrater` AND `NIntegrate` are derelict. We'll see.)

Comment: I am mystified by the Hypergeometric1F1Regularized function. I would like to put this in an answer so you can see my text better, but I really have a question so think it would be wrong to post it as an answer. It is too long for one comment so I will break it into parts.

Comment: When I Integrate[p[q,C,n,s,\[Nu],\[Mu]],{q,0,1},Assumptions->{C,n,s,\[Nu],\[Mu]}\[Element]Reals] it results in ConditionalExpression[C Gamma[4n\[Mu]]Gamma[4n\[Nu]]Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[4n\[Nu],4n(\[Mu]+\[Nu]),4ns],(n>0&&\[Mu]>0&&\[Nu]>0)||(n<0&&\[Mu]<0&&\[Nu]<0)].

Comment: When I compute the inidivual terms Gamma[4n\[Mu]], Gamma[4n\[Nu]], and Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[4n\[Nu],4n(\[Mu]+\[Nu]),4ns] I get 362880, 362880 and 1.24459*10^47 for n=2500, s=0.0001, \[Nu]=0.001, \[Mu]=0.001. Yet when I multiply all three together I get 1.7953*10^-6. This leaves me totally confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is numerically unstable for some parameter ranges.

We shall show a simple example.

Your normalized distribution is given by

```
p[q_, n_, \[Mu]_, \[Nu]_, s_] := 
 Exp[4 n s q] q^(4 n \[Nu] - 
     1) (1 - q)^(4 n \[Mu] - 1)/(Gamma[4 n \[Mu]] Gamma[
      4 n \[Nu]] Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[4 n \[Nu], 4 n (\[Mu] + \[Nu]), 
      4 n s])
```

Check normalization: ok for all parameters if {n>0,[Mu]>0,[Nu]>0}

```
Integrate[p[q, n, \[Mu], \[Nu], s], {q, 0, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> {n > 0, \[Mu] > 0, \[Nu] > 0}]

(* Out[3]= 1 *)
```

Calculate the k-th moment (k>=0)

```
Integrate[q^k p[q, n, \[Mu], \[Nu], s], {q, 0, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> {n > 0, \[Mu] > 0, \[Nu] > 0, k >= 0}]

(* Out[6]= (Gamma[k + 4 n \[Nu]] Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[k + 4 n \[Nu], 
  k + 4 n (\[Mu] + \[Nu]), 4 n s])/(
Gamma[4 n \[Nu]] Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[4 n \[Nu], 4 n (\[Mu] + \[Nu]), 
  4 n s]) *)
```

Now look at the normalization with NIntegrate for very simple values of the parameters

```
Table[NIntegrate[p[q, n, 1, 1, 1], {q, 0, 1}], {n, 1, 20}]
```

> During evaluation of In[63]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to
>   converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in q near
>   {q} = {0.673813}. NIntegrate obtained 0.8149444193581905`and
>   0.0004882716173466382` for the integral and error estimates. >>

```
(* 
Out[63]= 
{1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.00009, 1.00112, 1.02324, 1.25255, 2.32575, 
-0.0207066, 0.00601814, 0.814944, 1., 1., 1., 1.} 
*)
```

Hence I recommend to look very carefully at the parameter values of your problem, and check first if NIntegrate gives 1.

PS: why do you attempt to use NIntegrate at all?

Regards,
Wolfgang

Comment: Thank you. I used `NIntegrate` when I realized that the individual probabilities I could calculate would never sum up to 1 although `Integrate` said the opposite. I didn't know the concept of `numerical stability`.

Comment: Your answer already helps a lot but there's a point I still don't get. It seems to me that the concept of `numerical stability` only applies to the function `NIntegrate` and not to the function `Integrate` neither when I just calculate the probability $p(q \space |\space μ,ν,n,s)$. So I still don't fully understand why my plot shows a curve that seem to integrate to a value that is closer to the result of `NIntegrate` than to 1. Does my misunderstanding make sense?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what is going on with the different results of `Integrate` and `NIntegrate`. This does not mean that the analytic form of $C$ is erroneous.

Note that plotting the likelihood function (using the expression of $C$ provided by `Integrate` and the parameter values you used) over a resticted range of $s$ (instead of $[0,1]$) clearly shows that the log-likelihood is maximized for a non-zero value.

```
Plot[Log[(E^(4 n q s) (1 - q)^(-1 + 4 n \[Mu]) q^(-1 + 4 n \[Nu]))/(
   Gamma[4 n \[Mu]] Gamma[4 n \[Nu]] Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[
     4 n \[Nu], 4 n (\[Mu] + \[Nu]), 4 n s])] //. {q -> 0.75, 
   n -> 100/(40 \[Nu]), \[Nu] -> \[Mu], \[Mu] -> 10^(-6)}, {s, 
  10^(-7), 10^(-5)}, AxesLabel -> {"s", "log(likelihood)"}]
```

[image]

The exact value can be found by `FindMaximum` (a good initial estimate is required)

```
FindMaximum[
 Log[(E^(4 n q s) (1 - q)^(-1 + 4 n \[Mu]) q^(-1 + 4 n \[Nu]))/(
   Gamma[4 n \[Mu]] Gamma[4 n \[Nu]] Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[
     4 n \[Nu], 4 n (\[Mu] + \[Nu]), 4 n s])] //. {q -> 0.75, 
   n -> 100/(40 \[Nu]), \[Nu] -> \[Mu], \[Mu] -> 10^(-6)}, {s, 
  10^(-6)}]
```

> {1.66, {s -> 2.75*10^-6}}

Comment: Thanks a lot. That will help as well. I was kinda lost and I realized my post may contain two distinct questions. You answered the ML-method related question. +1